# CakePHP Google Analytics Plugin

Tags: cakephp, google-api, google-analytics-api, cakephp-2.1

I am building a Core Reporting system App. And right now i am using http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ for the purpose. But i want to move my application into CakePHP to leverage the Framework.

How can i dump the php client in to vendors folder and leverage that inside CakePHP ?
I have never used a 3rd party script inside cakephp. Is there any Write up that can get me started ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Loading Vendor Files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files) in the cookbook should get you started.